# Где ошибка в коде (в моей игре)?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

Создал игру но она работает некорректно, где ошибка?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<random>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

char player1[30];
char player2[30];
char pole[3][3];
bool step;

void instruction();
bool input();
bool win();

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    instruction();
    system("cls");

    cout << "Введите имя 1 игрока ";
    cin.getline(player1, 30);
    cout << "Введите имя 2 игрока ";
    cin.getline(player2, 30);

    srand(time(NULL));
    if (rand() & 1)
        step = true;
    else step = false;

    while (!win())
    {
        system("cls");
        if (!input())
        {
            cout << "Вы ввели неверное значение! Повторите пожалуйста ";
            _getch();
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    if (step)
        cout << "Победил(а) " << player1 << endl;
    else cout << " Победил(а) " << player2 << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;




}

void instruction()
{
    cout << "\t \t \t *** КРЕСТИКИ -XO- НОЛИКИ ***\n \n";
    cout << "Правила: \n";
    cout << "Играют 2 игрока на поле 3х3 \n";
    cout << "Побеждает тот кто составит выйграшную комбинацию \n \n";

    int l = 0;

    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << "| " << l + 1 << " ";
            pole[i][j] = char(49 + 1);
            l++;

        }
         cout << "|";       
         cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nДля хода нажмите цифру ячейки поля \n";
    cout << "Для начала игры нажмите клавишу";

    _getch();
}



bool input()
{
    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << "| " << pole[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "|";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    if (step)
        cout << "Ходит " << player1 << " : ";
    else cout << "Ходит " << player2 << " : ";

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 1 || n > 9)
        return false;
    int i, j;
//////////////////////////////////////////  ????????????
    if (n %3 == 0)
    {
        i = n / 3 - 1;
        j = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        j = n % 3 - 1;
        i = n / 3;
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////

    if (pole[i][j] == 'O' || pole[i][j] == 'X')
        return false;

    if (step)
    {
        pole[i][j] = 'X';
        step = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pole[i][j] = 'O'; step = true; 
    }
    return true;
    }
bool win()
{
    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
        if ((pole[i][0] == pole[i][1]) && (pole[i][0] == pole[i][2]))
            return true;
        else
            if ((pole[0][i] == pole[1][i]) && (pole[0][i] == pole[2][i]))
                return true;
            else if ((pole[0][0] == pole[1][1] && pole[0][0] == pole[2][2])||(pole[0][2] == pole[1][1] && pole[0][2] == pole[2][0]))
                return true;


    return false;


}
```

Comment: Скорее всего Вам необходимо провести отладку, в тех блоках где она, по вашему мнению, работает не так как надо. И тогда Вы сами решите свою проблему.

Comment: Уважаемый пользователь! Ни я, ни один из присутствующих здесь - НЕ ТЕЛЕПАТ! И мы, конечно, не в курсе как должна корректно работать Ваша программа, и что конкретно Вы считаете ошибкой! И впредь не задавайте подобных  вопросов без подробного описания проблемы!

Answer (score 3):

Никогда не называйте переменную строчной буквой l, будете постоянно путать ее с единицей! Именно это и произошло в вашем случае - в функции instruction при инициализации поля у вас написано 49 + 1 вместо 49 + l, отсюда и глюки. Если же вы так и хотели написать, то функция win у вас работает в корне не правильно, т.к. она ищет одинаковые значения вдоль линий, но пустые ячейки ведь тоже одинаковые.

Так же, я немного подзабыл си и не помню как работает cin.getline, но скорее всего для переменной надо выделить на один байт больше, чем максимальная длина строки, для нулевого байта (признака окончания строки).